# Is there lodash shortcut for spawning object from key name list and evaluator for them?

Tags: lodash

I often spawn Object from mapping certain field for their respective names, like this

```
_.zipObject(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'].map(evaluatorFN))
```

or

```
fields = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
_.zipObject(fields, fields.map(evaluatorFN))
```

This works, but I don't like that I have to save ['A', 'B', 'C'] in extra var, cause this is less explicit(if it's unique), and, apparently writing 2 times is even worse idea.

Is there something in lodash, which would do the same, but would be called like

```
_.constructFromArrayFN(['A', 'B', 'C'], evaluatorFN)
```

I cannot find anything that would work as constructFromArrayFN in lodash, does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash doesn't have a function for this specific case, but you can easily create one:

```js
const zipValues = (fields, evaluatorFN) =>
  _.zipObject(fields, fields.map(evaluatorFN))

const result = zipValues(['A', 'B', 'C'], str => str.repeat(3))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you are using lodash globally, and not via imports, you can use [`_.mixin()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mixin) to add the function to the global lodash (`_`):

```js
_.mixin({
  zipValues(fields, evaluator){
    return _.zipObject(fields, fields.map(evaluator))
  }
});

const result = _.zipValues(['A', 'B', 'C'], str => str.repeat(3))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```